# Вложенный массив в vb6

Tags: vb6

Что использовать, если мне нужен вложенный массив? Т.е., допустим я обращался `mass[0]` и получал в качестве результата массив с данными.

Например чтобы это выглядело так:

```
mass {(1):("Петя",23);(2):("Вася",18);...}
```

Comment: А двумерный массив не годится?

Comment: А, ну как вариант. Только проблема ещё в том, что количество строк неизвестно, т.е. нужен динамический массив.

Comment: @TemaGr у вас точно VB6? в нем же индексация с 1, и обращения к массиву по круглым скобкам. как у вас вообще `mass[0]` работает?

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать массив не конкретного типа, а пользовательского, состоящего из уже существующих.

Для поставленного примера можно сделать так:

Некий модуль:

```
public type UserData  'Объявим тип *
  UserName as string    'Теперь добавим в наш тип строковый параметр
  UserAge as byte       'и числовой
end type              'Закончили

public Users(15) as UserData  'Теперь создаём сам массив
```

---

**public type UserData  'Объявим тип *** - Если создавать пользовательский тип данных НЕ в модуле, а где-либо ещё (на форме, например), то он может быть только "местным", "локальным" (вместо **public** - **private**, иначе IDE будет ругаться) и из других форм/модулей его уже не будет видно (как несуществующий, ибо существует локально), поэтому все важные переменные и типы, которые надо обрабатывать на нескольких формах/в нескольких модулях следует помещать в модули и объявлять, как публичные.

Далее в программе (в любом модуле/форме/контроле и т.д.) делаем так:

```
Users(0).UserName = "Вася"  'Присваиваем строковые данные нулевому массиву
Users(0).UserAge = 18       'Присваиваем числовые данные
Users(1).UserName = "Петя"  'А вот и Петя
Users(1).UserAge = 23       'Ему 23
```

Для получения аналогично:

```
Age = Users(0).UserAge     'Вернёт 18, ибо Васе 18 лет - присвоили выше :)
```

Краткое дополнение - нумерация массивов начинается с нуля, если только при объявлении не было указано обратное, например:

```
dim A(2 to 10)  'Массив А, содержащий 9 значений с нумерацией от 2 до 10 включительно
```